# Building iOS app, website, and backend

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services

I've only recently started to delve into how building apps work. I'd like to know what the general setup is for a mobile app and a website, in which users can update information on the app through the website.

I'm trying to learn how to make an iOS app with Swift, and use Amazon Web Services as the backend for it. If I wanted to then make a website that would change data on the mobile app, would I have to create a website from scratch with Ruby or Python, and then somehow connect that to the same AWS backend that my iOS app uses?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a very broad question, with lots of possible answers, but here are some of the options:

- you have a native (Objective-C or Swift) iOS app, with its own UI, etc. It exchanges data with your back-end server, which stores stuff in a database and/or forwards messages between clients. Then, you have a website, using any language/framework you want, accessing the same database.
- you have a web-based application: you use exactly the same code (with responsive design of course), serve it from your servers using any language/framework you want, and just embed that in a web view in your app
- you have an hybrid application: this is close to the previous option, but you do most of the coding client-side (i.e. using Javascript, possibly with frameworks such as Angular) within a Cordova/Phonegap app. The same app would then be deployable as a native app as well as served as a website. You would just have back-end code on the server.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look to start with the first option you mentioned, since I do want the website to be totally different from how the app works.

Answer (score 4):

Usually, most data is stored on a website. Your website can have ways of viewing the data, such as web apps, like jcaron said. An app is usually used for viewing data from the website. When I develop apps (with Swift) I setup a database on a website and connect it to the app using PHP scripts. Then I make the app, with it's own UI, which does HTTP requests to the website and uses the data.