# Rails Website and IOS app

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, database

I have right now a ruby on rails website that uses devise for authentication and a development database.
I am also currently building an IOS app that should access the users information (tasks they have created) and display it on the website and the app.

I figured that both website and app should just talk to the same database, based on this post([Building iOS app, website, and backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35214634/building-ios-app-website-and-backend)). I was wondering how I should handle the registrations through devise on the mobile app.

The app will be for IOS.

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app Something along the lines of this I would use to connect to the database

Comment: You'l have to do token based authentication for registering and all other actions for mobile